# Compile task is running successful but not generating any class files

Tags: gradle

I want to implement a gradle build script which compiles some java classes and copy it to to a tomcat directory. I dont want to use Gradle Java plugin since it does many things which are not relevant. I want to define my own compile & deploy tasks which does it. I have implemented it as below -

```
task compile (type: JavaCompile) {
    source = fileTree('$srcdir')
    destinationDir = file('$builddir')
    classpath = files('lib')
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
}


task deploy (type: Copy) {
    dependsOn compile
    from fileTree('build') {
        include fileTree('classes')
    }
    from fileTree('lib') {
        include '*'
    }
into '${tomcathome}//${projectname}'
}
```

I have not touched deploy task yet. When i am running compile tasks it is running successful but not generating any class files. I am expecting it to be generated under /build directory.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: When using variables you need to use GString "" and its $buildDir

Comment: Same problem for `'$srcdir'`. I don't know where you specified `srcdir`, but you won't be able to use it with a simple String (single quotation marks), because this way it will always be interpret as the literal location (a subfolder called `$srcdir` in this case). You need to use a GString (double quotation marks), as @LazerBanana already stated. Or you could just use the variable instead of wrapping it into a GString: `fileTree(srcdir)`

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. This string literal concept did help me to address my issue. I was looking to configure these parameters - srcdir, builddir and similar others in gradle.properties. These file is at same layer as my build.gradle but i cannot get the values of the parameters if configured in gradle.properties. Do i have to do something else to let gradle load this property file before starting the build tasks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarise the comments in the answer, you need to use [GString](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/groovy-goodness-string-strings-strings.html) like @lu.koerfer stated

> this way it will always be interpreted as the literal location (a subfolder called $srcdir in this case)

This is needed when using variables inside a string, if don't need to use it in a string then don't (then you don't need a dollar sign).

Not sure how your variables are defined but for build and source directories you should ideally use Gradle provided variables

`buildDir` to point the build directory

`sourceSets.main.java.getSrcDirs()` to get source directories (depending on the project structure)

or `sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs` but note this is going to return the collection of your source directories, depending how you specified your sourceSets, or if you haven't at all then by default is going to return a maven convention structure `src/main/java`

For some global variables please read about [Ext variables](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-create-global-variable-which-can-be-share-with-multiple-project/9141)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. This string literal concept did help me to address my issue. I was looking to configure these parameters - srcdir, builddir and similar others in gradle.properties. These file is at same layer as my build.gradle but i cannot get the values of the parameters if configured in gradle.properties. Do i have to do something else to let gradle load this property file before starting the build tasks

Comment: Read about ext variables